# Query geoserver and get all the points in a radius of 500m

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, circle

I'm using postgresql+postgis, openlayers(js) and geoserver. I have a table for hotels (id, name, geometry).

What I'm trying to do is, click on the map and place a point and show me all the hotels (points) in a radius of 500m or 1 km of that point.

My main problem is asking geoserver for the points in 500m or 1 km of the point I just made.

Do I have to use some function? Or create a sql query? If so where and how?

In the cql_filter, what Point is the lon and lat? and the the_geom is correct or should i have geometry? (because geometry is what I have in my table)

My code is 900 lines long, so I will just place here how I contact geoserver, but if you need the whole code just tell me.

```
var formatWFSPM = new ol.format.WFS();
var sourceVector_hotels = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        "use strict";
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/trabalhois/wms', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'hotels',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                cql_filter: DWITHIN(the_geom, Point(-88 38),0.5,kilometers),
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            formatWFSPM = new ol.format.WFS();
            sourceVector_hotels.addFeatures(formatWFSPM.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
        maxZoom: 19
    }))
});
```

Pictures of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: How I have]
[image: How I want]

Sorry If I sound so noob, but that is because I'm new with this type of geographic stuff.

Comment: You must make your application to do WFS request with DWithin filter.

Comment: I don't suppose you could give me an example with the code I have above? It would be very helpful, thanks